# pset8: "This RSS feed URL is deprecated" is returned in every JSON object returned. What does this mean?

Tags: python, google-maps, rss, cs50

From the execution of the function of articles in application.py, I am able to get the JSON of articles, however the first link is always that of the Google news headlines page and title is always This RSS feed URL is deprecated. I am suppose to return a JSON object of 5 news links, after the user clicks on a selected marker on the Google Map (which fires "geo" which is the postal code of the place marked by the selected marker).

As such:

```
  {
    "link": "https://news.google.com/news", 
    "title": "This RSS feed URL is deprecated"
  }

  {
    "link": "http://news.google.com/news/url?
sa=t&fd=R&ct2=us&usg=AFQjCNHkxhtDRE9JHS9dxvxZigP-pPRMrQ&clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&ei=hU0KWpDlIoa38QWkp6PgBw&url=http://cambridge.wickedlocal.com/news/20171113/cambridge-students-transform-foundry-building-into-public-safety-training-site", 
    "title": "Cambridge students transform Foundry Building into public safety training site - Wicked Local Cambridge"
  }
]
```

Is it because of my code and if yes, **what leads to the return of this link and what does the title 'This RSS feed URL is deprecated' mean?**

Here's my code for articles:

```
@app.route("/articles", methods=["GET"])
def articles():
    """Look up articles for geo."""
    # Get the postal code from geo in the HTML.
    geo = request.args.get("geo")
    if not geo:
        raise RunTimeError("missing geo")

    else:
        articles = lookup(geo)
        articles_list = []
        if len(articles) > 5:
            for i in range(0, 5):
                articles_list.append(articles[i])
            return jsonify(articles_list)
        else:
            return jsonify(articles_list)
```

Turns out if I change the "for-loop"'s range to (1,6), it'll return me the right articles! But I don't understand why the first article will always be that of the homepage of Google News?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Google News is deprecating RSS feed URLs in favour of making some necessary improvement to the system. It is not related to your code in any way.

There's an article on the matter [here](https://searchengineland.com/google-news-deprecate-old-rss-feed-urls-december-1-2017-286149).